# How to rotate data among 3 groups?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, sorting

Let's say I have group A, B and C. Each group has X number of items each. What is the algorithm to used so that I could sort out all the items here in such a way that I take one from each group every time.

IE.
Given that A and B have 2 items, and C has 3. I should show a list like this:

> ```
>  1. A - Item 1
>  2. B - Item 1
>  3. C - Item 1
>  4. A - Item 2
>  5. B - Item 2
>  6. C - Item 2
>  7. C - Item 3
> ```

I'm pulling this data from a MySQL DB so if it's at all possible to do this in MySQL, I would appreciate to know.

So what's a good algorithm for this? I would imagine this would be a common scenario for a bunch of things so there should already be some efficient way to do this. I don't know what to Google for though, I'm not getting any good results.

Anyone care to shine some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish such result by the following query:

[***You can rotate data among any groups actually***]

```
SELECT 
t.item_type,
t.item_name
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
 item_type,
 item_name,
 IF(@prev = item_type , @rank := @rank + 1 , @rank := 0) rankNumber,
 @prev := item_type
 FROM itemstable , (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rank := 0) vars
 ORDER BY item_type,item_name
) t
ORDER BY t.rankNumber,t.item_type;
```

---

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a00fe/1/0)

---

**TEST DATA WITH SCHEMA:**

(***If you cannot access SQL FIDDLE***)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `itemstable`;
CREATE TABLE `itemstable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_type` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
INSERT INTO `itemstable` VALUES ('1', 'A', 'ITEM 1');
INSERT INTO `itemstable` VALUES ('2', 'A', 'ITEM 2');
INSERT INTO `itemstable` VALUES ('3', 'B', 'ITEM 1');
INSERT INTO `itemstable` VALUES ('4', 'B', 'ITEM 2');
INSERT INTO `itemstable` VALUES ('5', 'C', 'ITEM 1');
INSERT INTO `itemstable` VALUES ('6', 'C', 'ITEM 2');
INSERT INTO `itemstable` VALUES ('8', 'C', 'ITEM 3');
```

Running the above query on this test data you will get an output like below:

```
item_type     item_name
A              ITEM 1
B              ITEM 1
C              ITEM 1
A              ITEM 2
B              ITEM 2
C              ITEM 2
C              ITEM 3
```

**Explanation:**

- First sort your data according to `ITEM_TYPE (A,B,C...)` and then
  again sort this sorted data based on `ITEM_NAME (ITEM1,ITEM2...)`.

> ```
>  item_type   item_name
>    A          ITEM 1
>    A          ITEM 2
>    B          ITEM 1
>    B          ITEM 2
>    C          ITEM 1
>    C          ITEM 2
>    C          ITEM 3
> ```

- So that the items under the same type stick together having a sorted
  order among them.
- Now imagine you are walking through this **double** sorted data .
- If you find an item belonging to a previously seen ITEM_TYPE then you
  will assign an incremental rank number to this just seen item.
- Otherwise, (that means you have just seen an item belonging to a new
  ITEM_TYPE) you will assign a rank number which is zero.

Comment: What does the IF do there? I'm kinda confused since my actual query includes a `left join` which makes it a little hard to translate.

Comment: I've added an explanation. Please check now.

Comment: How would this work with a `left join` or `inner join`?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` with which table on which condition? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: If you want to make join with `itemsTable` then you can put the join clause After **From itemsTable** in the above query. Like this `...From itemsTable INNER JOIN YOUR_ANOTHER_TABLE 
ON YOUR_ANOTHER_TABLE.FIELD = itemstable.FIELD,  (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rank := 0) vars....`

Comment: I edited your fiddle to reflect a somewhat similar table structure. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eae24 (edit. I changed the group IDs to even make it closer to my DB -- thought that would matter).